# How to convert .it file to .mp3?

Tags: audio, mp3, encoding

I tried numerous googlings, but found only software that isn't free.

I did this once, but I forgot how! What is the free app to do this?

Comment: Besides Winamp, you can try [FormatFactory](http://www.pcfreetime.com) and even [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org) with the in-built [converter component](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Converter) and [LAME EXE](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=LAME).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

Load up the file in [Winamp](http://www.winamp.com/media-player/all), use the Disk Writer plugin, and write it to a WAV file on the hard drive. Then you can burn straight to a CD without converting from MP3 or anything.

Try **2Wav** or **IT to XM converter** from [here](http://www.maz-sound.com/convert.html).

Comment: Disk Writer plugin did the job, though i need to use GoldWave to write the mp3 from that wav file now. Its a bit weird to use though, had to CTRL+ALT+DEL my winamp few times to just exit it. Edit: oops, i used wrong plugin. The good thing is that i got it working. (i used disk writer plugin (installed by default?)). Edit2: How the hell i disable this?!

Comment: I solved it now; i had to click the "Nullsoft WaveOut Output" plugin from that list and close it and then restart winamp, and now it outputs the sound into my speakers instead of trying to use some disk writer thing.

Comment: Actually you need to choose "Nullsoft directsound output", waveout made the winamp change my global sound volume if i adjusted volume, really annoying.